# CORE_PEER_ADDRESS in chaincode-docker-devmode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I am following the tutorial Chaincode for Developers and in the section Testing Using dev mode in Terminal 2 there is the following instantiation of the environment variable

`CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer:7052`

Could you please tell me what is the purpose of this variable and why the port of the used peer is 7052?

I couldn't find in the docker-compose file a container running on this port..

Answer (score 0):

Generally,chain code is going to run on containerized environment, but for dev activities like code/test/deploy, we have a sample folder called Chaincode-dev in fabric samples .It is of optimized with limited orderer,peer,cli. Normally we specify chaincode address as 7052,8052,... and chaincode will be maintained by peers (you can check these parameters in docker-composebase.yaml files ),but now here in dev --peer-chaincodedev mode , chaincode is running from user,you check parameters with chaincode won't be present,so these variables are exporting from user.